Partial Record invalidates object literal, but not as return type of function
I've defined the following types:
type MyKey = 'a' | 'b'
type MyKeyRecord = Partial<Record<MyKey, number>>

As expected, MyKeyRecord invalidates object literals with extra properties:
const bad: MyKeyRecord = {
    'a': 1,
    'c': 3
}
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''c'' does not exist in type 'Partial<Record<MyKey, number>>'.

But if I define a function type with MyKeyRecord as the return type:
type MyKeyFunction = () => MyKeyRecord

a function returning the same object literal is not invalidated.
const shouldFailFn: MyKeyFunction = () => {
    return {
        'a': 1,
        'c': 3
    }
}

Playground
Why is this happening? How can I enforce strict property checks here?

Some additional points:

If there are no valid properties, the function return also invalidates:
const badFn: MyKeyFunction = () => {
    return {
        'c': 3
    }
}
// Type '() => { c: number; }' is not assignable to type 'MyKeyFunction'.
//   Type '{ c: number; }' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Record<MyKey, number>>'.


I could create a new strictly-typed variable within the function, but I'd rather avoid that.



From an external consumer of your function (where the return type is used), the value is valid
